# How do I find the total number of JSON entries?

Tags: jquery, json

I just started learning JSON/jquery and I can't figure out how to determine the total entries that resulted for behance's API call. The call generates 12 user entries as shown below, but I know there are more than 12 users on behance. How do I get the total number of users?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var apiKey  = '###';

        (function() {
            var behanceUserAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/?callback=?&api_key='+ apiKey+'<?php echo $search; ?>';

            function setUserTemplate() {
                var userData     = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
                    getTemplate = $('#profile-template').html(),
                    template     = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
                    result       = template(userData);

                $('#content').html(result);

            };


            $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function(user) {
                var data = JSON.stringify(user);
                sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
                setUserTemplate();
            });

        })();       
    });
    </script>
```

I'm trying to count the total number of users that would be generated from the API call. The call generates 12 users and it's page 1 by default. How do I count the total number of users that would result from "behanceUserAPI'?

Thanks!

Comment: Load it into a JS variable, and use `.length`

Comment: Seems like OP is asking how to get total users not total users in his JSON? Or thats what the post seems like its implying when he says..."The call generates 12 user entries as shown below, but I know there are more than 12 users on behance. How do I get the total number of users"

Comment: Hi Scott, that's exactly that I had in mind. Though when I loaded .length into a JS variable, it would return "12". I'm also using handlebars templates if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean just a count, if so:

```
data.users.length
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it still only returns 12 users. I'm trying to count the total number of users.

Comment: I just added the jquery I'm using to make the API call. Any ideas on counting the total number of users generated from the call?

Comment: That would be a server side concern. I would write tests for the back end code to check it.